# PHPmailer failing if trying to send two emails in same script

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer to send emails and I've created a function that prepares the email and sends it. If I try to use this function more than once in a script it stops the script execution when it trys to send a second email using the same function.

my function:

```
public static function sendEmail($from, $fromName, $to, $subject, $body){
    require("includes/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->IsSMTP(true);
    $mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->Username = 'removed';
    $mailer->Password = 'removed';

    $mailer->From     = $from;
    $mailer->FromName = $fromName;
    $mailer->AddAddress($to);
    $mailer->Subject  = $subject;
    $mailer->Body     = $body;
    $mailer->WordWrap = 100;
    if ($mailer->Send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Is it anything to do with creating a new phpmailer object each time?

Comment: First of all, I would suggest to use require_once unless require

Comment: And activate your error reporting. There should be an error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `require_once()` instead of `require`